# По одним координатам то строит, то не строит маршрут

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

У меня возникла такая проблема, на сайте стоит Яндекс карта, которая строится по моим городам из БД, а точнее по координатам. То есть в один день у меня по одним координатам информации нет, захожу на следующий день по тем же координатам маршрут уже строится. В чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чаще всего проблемы с построением связаны со сложными многоточечными маршрутами и точками, находящимися на закрытых территориях. Попробуйте подправить координаты, вынеся их из таких территорий. Если это не так, нужны конкретные примеры и неплохо бы уточнить у Яндекса.